# c# allocate memory for array?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a array of a class but Unity throwing error when assigning values to arrays
`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`
The Code:

```
public class StringClass {
        public string name;
    }

    private void JsonParsing()
    {
       StringClass[] stringClass = new StringClass[3]; // am i not creating object for array in here?
        stringClass[0].name = "test0"; // Error
        stringClass[1].name = "test1";
        stringClass[2].name = "test2";
        stringClass[3].name = "test3";
```

The string array works perfectly fine but the class arrays just don't work properly

Comment: Why did you add the tag for the very ***very*** different language C?

Comment: As for your problem, how many elements in the array do you think `new StringClass[3]` creates? Why do you think it creates four elements?

Comment: Also `new StringClass[3];` creates an array - but what do you think is stored in this array at this point?

Comment: @UnholySheep isn't `new StringClass[3]` allocates memory?

Comment: for array .... not for elements ... unless it is a value type

Comment: See, e.g.: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/#default-value-behaviour

Comment: @UnholySheep got it, but when i'm using string array there is no such error like this. I wasn't doing `stringArray[1] = new string("dsad");` i just do `stringArray[1] = "sadas"`.  Is writing simple `stringArray[1] = "sadas"` creates array element too? is it because it's string?

Comment: On a separate note, why are you wrapping a string into a separate class? You could just have array of string objects doing the same thing, with less code.

Comment: `new string("dsad");` and `"sadas"` do (for the purposes of this question) the same thing - they both create a new string object somewhere (they only differ in details of how the object is handled internally, which is not relevant in this case). This is indeed a special case of how `string` works in C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @UnholySheep for pointing that there's two issues here.

**Array sizes**

`StringClass[3]` is just defining the size of the array to be 3. Which means you can use the array indexes 0-2. Sizes are always counted from 1, while indexes start at 0.

**Initiating array elements**

In the array you will need to initiate each element before setting its properties.

In your code you only set the size of the array and never initiated any elements in it. But you still tried changing the properties of a element, resulting in trying to access a null object.

Example:

```cs
class StringClass
{
    public string name;
}

internal class Program
{
    private void JsonParsing()
    {
        /*
           Since this isn't a value type array,
           we need to initiate each element before
           modifying any properties of it.
        */
        StringClass[] stringClass = new StringClass[2];

        // initiates the element of the first index
        stringClass[0] = new StringClass();

        // now we can modify this!
        stringClass[0].name = "test0";

        // Do it again on the next index
        stringClass[1] = new StringClass();
        stringClass[1].name = "test1";
    }
}
```

Comment: That is one issue, but not the cause of the runtime except OP gets. The array elements are all set to `null`, leading to a null-dereference

Comment: Saw that now, I was too hot on the trigger!

Comment: got it, i'm allocating memory for the array but i'm not creating class on list elements right?

Comment: But is initiating elements of array exclusive to classes?

Comment: [Arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/#default-value-behaviour) will tell you about default values. Value-type arrays (string, int, bool,) will default to 0. Type arrays such as this example, will default to null.

Comment: @Bagbaq what you allocate at first is a `StringClass[]` -> it's a class (=reference type) -> the array itself only holds **references** (basically `int` pointers) - the actual allocation is happening once you create instances of `StringClass`